# Why does calculateAccumulatedFrame give an unexpected CGRect?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift3

I'm trying to determine the right scaling factor for my node tree to make it fit exactly in my presentation rectangle, so I'm trying to find the smallest bounding rectangle around all my nodes. Apple's docs say that calculateAccumulatedFrame "Calculates a rectangle in the parent’s coordinate system that contains the content of the node and all of its descendants." That sounds like what I need, but it's not giving me the tight fit that I expect. My complete playground code is:

```
import SpriteKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let view:SKView = SKView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 800, height: 800))

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view

let scene:SKScene = SKScene(size: CGSize(width: 1000, height: 800))
scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.aspectFill
view.presentScene(scene)

let yellowBox = SKSpriteNode(color: .yellow, size:CGSize(width: 300, height: 300))
yellowBox.position = CGPoint(x: 400, y: 500)
yellowBox.zRotation = CGFloat.pi / 10
scene.addChild(yellowBox)

let greenCircle = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 100)
greenCircle.fillColor = .green
greenCircle.position = CGPoint(x: 300, y: 50)
greenCircle.frame
yellowBox.addChild(greenCircle)

let uberFrame = yellowBox.calculateAccumulatedFrame()

let blueBox = SKShapeNode(rect: uberFrame)
blueBox.strokeColor = .blue
blueBox.lineWidth = 2
scene.addChild(blueBox)
```

And the results are:
[image: Playground results]

The left and bottom edges of the blue rectangle look good, but why are there gaps between the blue rectangle and the green circle on the top and right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The notion "frame" does funny things when you add a transform. The bounding box around the box and circle is a rectangle. You have rotated that rectangle. Therefore its corners stick out. The accumulated frame embraces that rotated rectangle, including the sticking-out corners. It does not magically hug the *drawn appearance* of the nodes (e.g. the circle).

[image]

Comment: That makes sense. When I read in the docs and saw "The frame takes into the account the cumulative effect of the xScale, yScale, and zRotation properties of each node in the subtree," I thought a rectangle was computed for each node (including scale and rotation) and then they were all unioned instead of what you described. Thanks.

Comment: Even if a rectangle is computed for each node, it is a _rectangle_. Pretend your circle is a rectangle and this will make much more sense to you. Indeed, _draw_ your circle as a rectangle; that will give you a much better idea of what is happening.

Comment: Good suggestion. Changing greenCircle to greenBox clearly shows the blueBox snug around both rotated squares. Thanks again.